# Debugging with EDC-TCF using localhost as target in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

As the topic says. I am trying to start a debug session of a C/C++ project with TCF as the debugger.
This is what I do, (I am on windows xp)

- I create a C/++ project, build it using mingw32-make.exe and generate
  a binary.
- Then I press Debug As->Debug Config->Target Communications Framework
- In that, I specify the project name, and in the Local File Path box i give the absolute path of the C/C++ project's binary.
- I give nothing in the Remote File Path since I am doing localhost.
- Then I run a TCF agent (which can be obtained by building TCF agent source).
- In the target tab in the debug config, I check "Use localhost as a target".
- And finally press Debug.

Now when the session starts, I get a tcf nullpointerexception and session doesnt even start.
Has anyone done this type of debugging?

Answer (score 1):

You compiled your project using mingw, there's no point in using tcf to do local debugging, just use CDT's default debugger gdb , specify full path to gdb(mingw/bin/gdb) in your debugger tab, and evertything should be ok

BTW. I just did a tcf local debugging as you did, it worked, only that I compiled my project using msvc toolchain. Maybe that's your problem